# python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

This time I am trying another example from [Solem's blog](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2012/08/reading-gauges-detecting-lines-and.html). It's a module that detects lines and circles in an image by using the Hough transform.
Here is the code (houghlines.py):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

"""
Script using OpenCV's Hough transforms for reading images of 
simple dials.
"""

# load grayscale image
im = cv2.imread("house2.jpg")
gray_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# create version to draw on and blurred version
draw_im = cv2.cvtColor(gray_im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_im, (0,0), 5)

m,n = gray_im.shape

# Hough transform for circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_im, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10, np.array([]), 20, 60, m/10)[0]

# Hough transform for lines (regular and probabilistic)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 20, 60)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 2, np.pi/90, 40)[0]
plines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 20, np.array([]), 10)[0]

# draw 
for c in circles[:3]:
 # green for circles (only draw the 3 strongest)
 cv2.circle(draw_im, (c[0],c[1]), c[2], (0,255,0), 2) 

for (rho, theta) in lines[:5]:
 # blue for infinite lines (only draw the 5 strongest)
 x0 = np.cos(theta)*rho 
 y0 = np.sin(theta)*rho
 pt1 = ( int(x0 + (m+n)*(-np.sin(theta))), int(y0 + (m+n)*np.cos(theta)) )
 pt2 = ( int(x0 - (m+n)*(-np.sin(theta))), int(y0 - (m+n)*np.cos(theta)) )
 cv2.line(draw_im, pt1, pt2, (255,0,0), 2) 

for l in plines:
 # red for line segments
 cv2.line(draw_im, (l[0],l[1]), (l[2],l[3]), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("circles",draw_im)
cv2.waitKey()

# save the resulting image
cv2.imwrite("res.jpg",draw_im)
```

When I execute the file in python by:

```
execfile('houghlines.py')
```

the following error comes up:

```
File "houghlines.py", line 24, in <module>
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 2, np.pi/90, 40)[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Do you guys have any idea how to solve it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Houghlines` function returns `None`.

Comment: @segfolt: yes, but the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlines) doesn't seem to indicate that is normal behaviour..

Comment: Ummm - what happens if you try `cv2.HoughLines(edges, 2, np.pi/90, 40, None)` ?

Comment: if I try your solution, the error "moves" to another line. This time is:
File "houghlines.py", line 25, in <module>
    plines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 20, np.array([]), 10)[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Meaning that now, HoughLinesP returns None. If you're unsure about the output of cv2-functions, try what happens if you input an 'empty' image, one of which you're sure that it contains no lines.

Comment: the picture that I am trying to check if there are straight lines is this: http://chrisglass.com/journal/images/2006/0705-house-drawing.jpg
Maybe the algorithm does not detect straight lines here?

Answer (score 8):

It is because of the threshold value in `lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 2, np.pi/90, 40)[0]`, the last argument you passed. It indicates minimum length to be considered as a line, 40 pixels in your case. Try decreasing it.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes HoughLines and HoughLinesP return none. I think this means "no lines". It's really surprising to me that the examples in the documentation don't account for it. Maybe it's a bug.

In any case you can stop the code from failing with a simple `if result != None:` or replacing the None with a default list like `(HoughLinesP(... args ...) or [[]])`. This won't fix the fact that your lines weren't detected, but it allows you to do something in that case instead of failing.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug but just a missing check statement. I've just checked the `cpp` example equivalent for the Hough lines in the git repo and there is a check. There (in C++) a vector of lines is initialized on the stack and passed to the Hough line function. After that a check is done whether it contains anything. I will file an issue and a patch.

Comment: A minor point: `if result is not None:` is more Pythonic than `if result != None:`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the threshold value will work:

```
canny = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3) 

lines = cv2.HoughLines(canny,1,numpy.pi/180,40) 

print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also dealing with this error. When function `cv2.HoughCircles` doesn't detect any circle, it will return None. So I had two ways to solve it as follows:

- Use **try/exception** to surround your code block

```py
 try:
    ...
 except Exception as e:
    print 'There is no circles to be detected!'
```

- Use **if/else** to avoid operate None object

```py
 if circles is not None:
   ...
 else:
   print 'There is no circles to be detected!'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to overcome this:

```
    lines = []
    linesDetected = False
    while not linesDetected:
        lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 30, minLineLength = 60, maxLineGap=300)
        try:
            if len(lines) !=0:
                linesDetected = True
        except:
            linesDetected = False
```